# if else statement running like what i need something went wrong in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i have 2 button accept and reject
when i die dump request is coming fine with accept id 2 and reject id 3
but i try to add if statement its bring me only accept skip reject

here is my code

```
 $interview = Interview::find($request->id);
    $user = Currentuser::where('id', $interview->CompanyID)->first();
    if ($request->Status = '2') {


                 $data = []; // Empty array

                Mail::send('email.useracceptjob', $data, function($message) use ($user){

                    $message->to($user->Email)->subject('Your Job Accepted By user');

                });
             }
             elseif ($request->Status = '3') {


                 $data = []; // Empty array

                Mail::send('email.userrejectjob', $data, function($message) use ($user){

                    $message->to($user->Email)->subject('Your Job Rejected By user');

                });
             }
             else{
                return response()->json(['code' => 500]);
             }
```

do i doing something wrong?
Help me Please

Comment: `==` comparison operator and `=`  is assignment operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical operator in your `if` statement is like `if ($request->Status = '2')` but you have to do it like `if ($request->Status == '2')` or if you need to check the same value and type of data use `if ($request->Status === '2')`

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must use double or triple equals when doing a logical compare

`$request->Status == '2'`

Of if you know it will be a string for sure, then triple equals is better

`$request->Status === '2'`